# "Team Explorer failed to complete the upload transaction on the Sharepoint site"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

> TF400151: Team Explorer failed to complete the upload transaction on the SharePoint site. Refresh and try again.

I got this error when I tried to upload some documents

What happened to my TFS2010?

Comment: This error occurs on TFS 2013 as well.

Answer (score 8):

TFS Error TF400151 may occur when a user attempts to upload a document that is still open on the client machine.  Make sure the document you are uploading is closed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the bug in Microsoft TFS as per my investigation.

- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758649/misleading-errors-in-vs-2012-and-sharepoint-foundation-2010

Comment: But it works in TFS server  as builder .But not normal in client  for builder.

Answer (score 0):

See that a file name doesn't contains invalid characters:

```
\ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ &
```